# The type or namespace name 'LinkedList' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

Tags: reference

I have a fresh install of Visual Studio, the following code gives me the error in the title.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
public class GenericCollection
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        // Create and initialize a new LinkedList.
        LinkedList<String> ll = new LinkedList<String>();
        ll.AddLast("red");
        ll.AddLast("orange");
        ll.AddLast("yellow");
        ll.AddLast("orange");

     // Display the contents of the LinkedList. 
        if (ll.Count > 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The item in the list is {0}.", ll.First.Value);
            Console.WriteLine("The item in the list is {0}.", ll.Last.Value);

            Console.WriteLine("The LinkedList contains:");
            foreach (String s in ll)
                Console.WriteLine("   {0}", s);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The LinkedList is empty.");
        }
    }
}
```

I am not even using a custom class. 
just from the System.Collections.Generic dll
I assume there is a problem with the references, since the code is correct.

Please help me , how can i fix this.
(PS: I am fairly new to coding)

Comment: What version of the .NET framework are you using?

Comment: 4.0.30319 . says in my about--> visual studio c# 2010

Comment: Check the project.  Right click the project in solution explorer and go to properties.  What does the Target framework say in the Application tab?

Comment: .Net framework 4 client profile

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that you may have accidentally removed the reference to `System`.  Do you see it in References in Solution Explorer?

Comment: Under References in Solution Explorer, there is nothing, its a blank. I have just installed visual studio c# and have changed nothing

Comment: Thanks ! , i added a reference to System.dll , had to find it since i couldnt find it under default , and the code worked. thanks a lot

Comment: Glad I could help!  I added an answer so you can mark this question as answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`System.Collections.Generic.LinkedList<T>` exists in the `System` (System.dll) assembly.
Make sure you have a project reference to this assembly.

You can view your existing references by expanding the *References* section under the project in *Solution Explorer*.